# socket.io passing info from backend to frontend

Tags: sockets, socket.io, frontend, backend, mern

sorry, still new to use this platform.
not so sure how to input a code block.
I am currently setting up a realtime application on web.
however, I am not able to passing info from backend to frontend with socket.io.

please instruct

would like to transfer the value of countOnlineUser to frontend and update the online status in frontend

backend as below

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  //listening to this ID or name or event
  console.log(`...User connected ${socket.id}`);

  socket.on("countOnlineUser", (countOnlineUser) => {
    countOnlineUser = socket.client.conn.server.clientsCount;
    socket.emit(countOnlineUser);
  });
}};
```

frontend as below

```
  const [onlineStatue, setOnlineStatus] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("countOnlineUser", (countOnlineUser) => {
      setOnlineStatus(countOnlineUser);
    });
  }, [socket]);


  return (
    <div>
      <div className="onlineStatusShowing">
        <p>There are {onlineStatue} people online.</p>
      </div>
    <div>
```

Comment: you never told the server to send the online user count. You told the server to send the count if the client asks for it, but you didn't tell the client to ask for it.

Comment: Is this node.js code? If so you should tag it as such.

Comment: @user253751 oh yea finally found it, you are right
.emit has to pair with .on